# Resting a radiator on metal brackets

Tags: cooling-system, pontiac, radiator, gm, g6

I have recently replaced the radiator in my 2006 Pontiac g6 GTP 3.9L. While installing the new unit I neglected to install the rubber feet between the rad and the frames lower bracket, which the rad unit rests on.

My question is, is this worth going back in and fixing, or am I worrying too much?

Comment: Yes, if you do not the metal will damage the new radiator.

Answer (score 6):

The vibration from the engine and driving will cause fretting which will wear away at the metal of the radiator. The softer metal will wear faster and will eventually make a hole in the base, most probably causing the base to crack and support for the radiator structure to fail.

Fit the rubber feet : you may find that all you need to do is to release the upper fixings and slide the feet in...